# Power BI - Set custom Y axis unit label

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

In a Power BI (working in Power BI-Desktop) line chart, I am charting a field that lists KBytes of data (Y axis) that was backed up on particular weeks (the X axis). The Y axis auto-generated hash marks are at, e.g., "200bn", "400bn" - 200 billion, 400 billion. Nothing wrong with that, except I'd like it to say 200 TB/400 TB (which should be set at 214.748 billion, etc.).

I can't find any way to get the units to shift from "bn" to "TB". Any thoughts? If I could do something sophisticated in PowerShell, I'd be happy to - I've done PS for years, but am just getting started at Power BI.

Format/Y-axis/Values/Display units only gives me the "Billions" option for data of this scale. I want the units to be "TB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure in the form:

```
Measure = SUM('Table'[Kbytes])
```

Use that for your y-axis.

You can then change the format to what ever you want by typing in the format well:

[image]

```
#,0,,,.0TB
```

Ensure displays units is set to none.

[image]

[image]